# How can i get the Wi-fi Mac Address of the device that are connected to my hotspot and save it to my database?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a android app and i want to get the Wi-Fi mac address of the device when connected to the mobile hotspot and save it to my database.

How can I do this?

Comment: [java android remote mac address](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+android+remote+mac+address&oq=java+android+remote+mac+address&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6073j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) looks promising

Answer (score 1):

After Android 6.0 Changes

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this
>   release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local
>   hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The
>   WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods
>   now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

Before Android 6.0 Changes the MAC address can be received via the [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();
```